# Get only Sub names

Tags: excel, vba

Using below code I am getting both Sub names and functions name, but I want only Sub names excluding function names, please suggest me for this, it will be really helpful for me

```
    Sub ListMacros()
    Dim VBComp As VBComponent
    Dim VBCodeMod As CodeModule
    Dim oListsheet As Object
    Dim StartLine As Long
    Dim ProcName As String
    Dim iCount As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oListsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    iCount = 1
    oListsheet.[a1] = "Macro"

    For Each VBComp In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
        Set VBCodeMod = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(VBComp.Name).CodeModule
        With VBCodeMod
            StartLine = .CountOfDeclarationLines + 1
            Do Until StartLine >= .CountOfLines
                oListsheet.[a1].Offset(iCount, 0).Value = _
                  .ProcOfLine(StartLine, vbext_pk_Proc)
                iCount = iCount + 1

                StartLine = StartLine + _
                  .ProcCountLines(.ProcOfLine(StartLine, _
                   vbext_pk_Proc), vbext_pk_Proc)
            Loop
        End With
        Set VBCodeMod = Nothing
    Next VBComp

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to add an Instr test for the phrase " Sub ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this lines:

```
If InStr(.Lines(StartLine, 2), "Function") = 0 Then
     iCount = iCount + 1
End If
'2 lines because sometimes it returns "" for only a line (from unknown reasons)...
```

after

```
oListsheet.[a1].Offset(iCount, 0).Value = _
                           .ProcOfLine(StartLine, vbext_pk_Proc)
```

Edited, to **return the standard module type, too**:

```
    If InStr(.Lines(StartLine, 2), "Function") = 0 Then
        If VBComp.Type = 1 Then
             oListsheet.[a1].Offset(iCount, 1).Value = VBComp.Name
        End If
        iCount = iCount + 1
    End If
```

Comment: Above code, skipping the function from this workbook only, it is not wokring for modules, please suggest for skip function from both wokrbook and module also

Comment: @A.Raut: Now, I am not in front of a computer, but I know that It works for standard modules, too. It doesn't work in class modules... It is a VBA bug. When I used it I skipped the class modules. If I remember well the class module type would be `vbext_ct_ClassModule` (not sure...). And you must skip them putting such a condition before `With VBCodeMod`, This line should look like:  `If Not VBComp.Type = vbext_ct_ClassModule Then`... Do not forget its `End If`.

Comment: Hi FaneDuru, Thanks for response, could you please suggest where i am going wrong, it doesnt work for even standard module

Comment: @A.Raut: I do not understand how this can be true... I edited the code and added a variant able to retrieve (in column B:B) the name of the analyzed standard modules. Please, test it and tell me if none for your standard module appears in B:B column...

Comment: Hi FaneDuru Thanks a lot !, I observed on above of the function I mentioned the comments about function, after removing comments, code is working properly, is there any way we can skip the any comments with functions

Comment: @A.Raut:  I do not understand what comments are you talking about...

Comment: below is the sample of function with comments

'****************Comment about function***********'
Function WriteCell(iRow As Integer)
End Function

Comment: @A.Raut:I do not see any comment in the sample function bellow. If you are referring to double `**`, these are not comments in VBA. It is a way to make the text bold in a comment... You wrongly used them in code.

Comment: please refer the sample from above comments

Comment: @A.Raut: Do you mean my code answer? Do you see comments in the code? Are you referring to something else? If yes, please better specify what comments...

Comment: I am mentioning comments which are explaining the code like this with single quote====> ' ******comment1***** when I remove the comments, then functions are not coming in the macro list.

Comment: @A.Raut: Sorry... I do  not see any such a comment. Please note that in VBA a comment starts with `'` character. `*` character is used **only in comments, NOT in code** (like I used here, now) in order to make the text between them bold. But this **does not work in code**! If you try referring to the line ` **If InStr(.Lines(StartLine, 2), "Function") = 0 Then...`, this is your "contribution" and it does not mean a comment. In fact, if you try referring to such characters, the code has to return an error on this specific line...

Comment: Hi Fane Duru, Sorry mistakenly I entered * in code, I have edited my below code, in code, I have added function for reference, you can see function write Cell with Comment, when I remove first three lines of the below code, then code the code list out the macros only, is there any way to avoid these lines for skipping the functions

Comment: @A.Raut: But I've just stated above: **"Please note that in VBA a comment starts with `'` character.**. I edited your code and commented the lines in discussion. Of course, if I correctly understand what you wanted... :) The code lines are now grayed out.

Comment: Hi @Fane.Duru, I mean to say not how to comment in vbscript but how can I avoid the comments in the existing macro as when I try to list down the macro's the user have already added a comment before it's macro or Function and when the list macro script is executed it avoids the Functions and also considers it as a macro because of the existing comment added by the user.That's why when I execute list macro vba then it also comes with the "Function" in the list. So here I want to avoid the list of macro with the macro avoiding the comments written by the user in the excel macro.

Comment: @A.Raut: Comments inside or outside procedures are not take in consideration by the code bellow.

Comment: Thanks a lot, FaneDuru for suggestions :), I have modified the code now its working

Answer (score 0):

```
' *****************************************************************************************
'  Connect to Siebel
' *****************************************************************************************
Function WriteCell(iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer, iColor As Integer, Msg As String)
    ViewsSheet.Cells(iRow, iCol).Font.ColorIndex = iColor
    ViewsSheet.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = Msg
End Function


Sub ListMacros()
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
         ActiveWorkbook.Save
           Dim VBComp As VBComponent
           Dim VBCodeMod As CodeModule
           Dim oListsheet As Object
        Dim StartLine As Long
        Dim ProcName As String
        Dim iCount As Integer
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       On Error Resume Next
       Set oListsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
       oListsheet.Name = "MacroList"
       iCount = 0
       oListsheet.[a1] = ""
       For Each VBComp In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
        Set VBCodeMod = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(VBComp.Name).CodeModule
        With VBCodeMod
        StartLine = .CountOfDeclarationLines + 1
        Do Until StartLine >= .CountOfLines
         oListsheet.[a1].Offset(iCount, 0).Value = .ProcOfLine(StartLine, vbext_pk_Proc)
           'If InStr(.Lines(StartLine, 2), "Function") = 0 Then
               iCount = iCount + 1
           'End If
          StartLine = StartLine + .ProcCountLines(.ProcOfLine(StartLine, vbext_pk_Proc), vbext_pk_Proc)
        Loop
       End With
       Set VBCodeMod = Nothing
        Next VBComp
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     Dim FilePath As String
     Dim CellData As String
     Dim LastCol As Long
     Dim LastRow As Long
     Dim i As Long
     Dim j As Long
     LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
     LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
     CellData = ""
     FilePath = "E:\Dir\Excel\MacroTxt\\MacroList2.txt"
     Open FilePath For Output As #2
     For i = 1 To LastRow
      For j = 1 To LastCol
       If j = LastCol Then
        CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value)
       Else
        CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value) + ","
       End If
      Next j
      Write #2, CellData
      CellData = ""
      Next i
      Close #2
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     End Sub
```